# Как инициализировать вложенную функцию или класс один раз для 2х файлов

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

можно ли как-то обыграть этот момент, когда мне необходимо использовать запущенный класс/вложенную_функцию (*ClassOrNestedFunction*) в двух разных файлах, но с одной инициализацией? Т.е. чтобы аутпут от *getStartTime* был одинаковый

Пример

```js
// FILE_0
const ClassOrNestedFunction = async()=>{
    await sleep(1000);

    let time = new Date().getTime();

    return {getStartTime: ()=>time};
};
// export for ClassOrNestedFunction
```

```js
// FILE_1
// import ClassOrNestedFunction from FILE_0
const {getStartTime} = await ClassOrNestedFunction();
console.log(getStartTime()); // unixtime_1
```

```js
// FILE_2
// import ClassOrNestedFunction from FILE_0
const {getStartTime} = await ClassOrNestedFunction();
console.log(getStartTime()); // unixtime_not1
```

---

Знаю, что можно просто прокинуть *ClassOrNestedFunction* внутри *FILE_1* когда он запускает *FILE_2*

Т.е. вот так:

```js
// FILE_1
// import ClassOrNestedFunction from FILE_0
// import file2 from FILE_2
const ClassOrNestedFunctionInited = await ClassOrNestedFunction();
const {getStartTime} = ClassOrNestedFunctionInited;
console.log(getStartTime()); // unixtime_1
// ...
file2(ClassOrNestedFunctionInited);
```

Comment: `export ClassOrNestedFunction()` экспортируйте результат вызова функции. а если класс - создайте инстанс класса и экспортируйте его (синглтон)

Answer (score -1):

Короче несколько путей решения:

---

1

[nörbörnën](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2659) say: `export ClassOrNestedFunction()` экспортируйте результат вызова функции; *а если класс - создайте инстанс класса и экспортируйте его*

(Не уверен, могу ошибаться, что запущенная функция попадет)

---

2

chatgpt подсказал решение через: `const cacheManager = require('cache-manager');`, но этот кейс работает максимум с объектами, а когда у тебя какой-нибудь большой инстанс там запущен и живет, то этот вариант не подходит

---

3

Есть вариант реализации через глобальную переменную, но этот кейс (так же как и первый) не подходит конкретно для лямбды, потому что *запущенный инстанс чего-то большого* передается меж всех тасков/инстансев лямбды

а так же вернемся ко 2му варианту - большой инстанс можно передавать, и конечно это ускорит выполнение последующих лямбд, но этот большой инстанс может в себе кучу всего содержать и непонятно как поведет себя его содержимое, ибо логика нацелена на то, что будет чистый код, чистые параметры в `ClassOrNestedFunction`..

---

4

Ну и самый банальный и простой способ, который я выбрал и сразу к нему шёл: запускать функцию внутри хендлера - чтобы она не попадала в глобалки, а затем передавать её как аргумент во вложенные файлы

Примерный код такой:

```js
// import file2;
import ClassOrNestedFunction from './ClassOrNestedFunction.js';

export const handler = async(event, context)=>{
    const active_ClassOrNestedFunction = await ClassOrNestedFunction();
    const {getStartTime} = active_ClassOrNestedFunction;

    console.log(getStartTime());

    const output = await file2.someFunctionInside(event, context, active_ClassOrNestedFunction).catch((e)=>false);

    return output || null;
};
```